# I am not able to Install one of my particular Angular Project using npm install

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to install my angular project which was working in one of my old laptops.currently when i am trying npm install it is throwing me a lot of error.Im attaching my log some help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

> shiva@shiva-X507UB:~/lokkaly-angular$ npm install
>
> > grpc@1.13.1 install /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403):
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.1/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.13.1 and
>   node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with
>   node-gyp) node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for
>   grpc@1.13.1 and node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to
>   source compile with node-gyp) node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection
>   closed while downloading tarball file gypgyp WARN download
>   NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp
>   v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR  WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
>   is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use
>   NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR gyp gypWARN  downloadWARN download
>   NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp
>   v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR  NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated
>   and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
>   gypgyp  WARNWARN  downloaddownload NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated
>   and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR 
>   NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp
>   v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR make: Entering directory
>   '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build' make: Entering
>   directory '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build'
>   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
>   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
>   rm: cannot remove
>   './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw':
>   No such file or directory grpc.target.mk:450: recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o' failed
>   make: ***
>   [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error
>   1 make: Leaving directory
>   '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build' gyp ERR! build
>   error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:254:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
>   4.15.0-43-generic gyp ERR! command "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   "--module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node"
>   "--module_name=grpc_node"
>   "--module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc"
>   "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build
>   error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
>   '/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node
>   /home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   --module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc
>   --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:978:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   command "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v
>   v0.10.3 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute
>   '/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node
>   /home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   --module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc
>   --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.oexec
>   install script Assembler messages:] | install: info lifecycle
>   grpc@1.13.1~install: Failed to exec install script Fatal error: can't
>   create
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o: No
>   such file or directory grpc.target.mk:450: recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o'
>   failed make: ***
>   [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o]
>   Error 1 make: Leaving directory
>   '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build' gyp ERR! build
>   error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:254:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
>   4.15.0-43-generic gyp ERR! command "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   "--module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node"
>   "--module_name=grpc_node"
>   "--module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc"
>   "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN optional SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents): npm WARN
>   notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! grpc@1.13.1
>   install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>   --library=static_library` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.13.1 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/shiva/.npm/_logs/2019-01-30T06_37_53_574Z-debug.log
>   shiva@shiva-X507UB:~/lokkaly-angular$ rm -rf node_modules && npm i
>
> > grpc@1.13.1 install /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403):
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.1/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.13.1 and
>   node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with
>   node-gyp) node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for
>   grpc@1.13.1 and node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to
>   source compile with node-gyp) node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection
>   closed while downloading tarball file gypgyp WARN download
>   NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp
>   v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR  WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
>   is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use
>   NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR gypgyp WARN  download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is
>   deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use
>   NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated
>   and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR gyp
>   WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed
>   in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR gyp WARN download
>   NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp
>   v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR make: Entering directory
>   '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build' make: Entering
>   directory '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build'
>   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
>   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
>   rm: cannot remove
>   './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw':
>   No such file or directory grpc.target.mk:450: recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o' failed
>   make: ***
>   [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error
>   1 make: Leaving directory
>   '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build' gyp ERR! build
>   error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:254:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
>   4.15.0-43-generic gyp ERR! command "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   "--module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node"
>   "--module_name=grpc_node"
>   "--module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc"
>   "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build
>   error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
>   '/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node
>   /home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   --module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc
>   --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:978:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   command "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v
>   v0.10.3 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute
>   '/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node
>   /home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>   --module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node
>   --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc
>   --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.oexec
>   install script ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.cc:78:1:
>   fatal error: opening dependency file
>   ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o.d.raw:
>   No such file or directory compilation terminated. grpc.target.mk:450:
>   recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o'
>   failed make: ***
>   [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o]
>   Error 1 make: Leaving directory
>   '/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/build' gyp ERR! build
>   error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:254:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
>   4.15.0-43-generic gyp ERR! command "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/shiva/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>   "--module=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node"
>   "--module_name=grpc_node"
>   "--module_path=/home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc"
>   "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/shiva/lokkaly-angular/node_modules/grpc gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN optional SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents): npm WARN
>   notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! grpc@1.13.1
>   install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>   --library=static_library` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.13.1 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/shiva/.npm/_logs/2019-01-30T07_10_21_999Z-debug.log

npm install is working for other projects but not for this one

I have tried maintaing the node,npm,angular cli versions to that of which was working in my old laptop

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

before you do npm install you have to download node.. link https://nodejs.org/en/download/